# Implement typing delay in ScalaJS?

Tags: scala.js, timedelay

I have a search input field in a ScalaJS app that fires off requests to a backend server whilst the user types in a city name.  However, I need to implement a delay so that the request is not fired until after a certain delay (say 1000ms).  Without such a delay, there is the chance that I'll get back false positives on the search (E.G. If the user wants to search for "paris", then there will be a false hit on "par" - a small town in Cornwall, England - when the third character is entered)

I've tried transcribing the JavaScript equivalent into Scala, but the setTimeout part doesn't seem to work.

```
import scala.scalajs.js.timers.{SetTimeoutHandle, clearTimeout, setTimeout}

private def delay = () => {
  // Set initial timeout to do nothing after 0 ms
  var handle: SetTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(0)(() => {})

  (fn: Function0[Unit], ms: Double) => {
    clearTimeout(handle)
    handle = setTimeout(ms)(fn)
  }
}
```

Then I'm handling the user input event using an Akka Actor

```
def receive = {
  /************************************************
   * Client event
   * The user has typed something into the search field
   */
  case evt: Event =>
    delay()(handleInput, 1000.0)
}
```

Where `handleInput` is the zero parameter function that obtains the user's input and then fires off a request to the backend.

The anonymous inner function that clears and then resets the timeout is executed, but the handleInput function never gets called

Thanks

Chris W

Comment: I've edited the original question in order to show what I've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are giving a function of type `() => Unit` to `setTimeout`, but [`setTimeout` takes a by-name parameter](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/latest/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.timers.package@setTimeout(interval:Double)(body:=%3EUnit):scala.scalajs.js.timers.SetTimeoutHandle). In other words, the argument to `setTimeout` should be a *statement* to execute when the timeout expires. If you give it a function, then after the timeout that function value will be *evaluated*, but the function will not be called!

It is similar to mistakenly trying to do

```scala
val result = fn // result is the *function* itself, but does not call it
```

instead of

```scala
val result = fn() // fn is called, result is what it returns
```

You can fix your call to `setTimeout` by replacing `fn` by `fn()`. Also, it is typically more idiomatic, in those circumstances, to use `{}` instead of `()` for the parameter to `setTimeout`, which also gives a visual clue that it is a by-name parameter:

```scala
(fn: Function0[Unit], ms: Double) => {
  clearTimeout(handle)
  handle = setTimeout(ms) {
    fn()
  }
}
```

You should also adapt your first dummy `setTimeout` for consistency, although since it is a dummy anyway, that will not change the behavior:

```scala
// Set initial timeout to do nothing after 0 ms
var handle: SetTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(0) {}
```

Comment: Great, that's fixed it!  Thanks for your explanation